# How to read attribute value from XmlNode in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Suppose I have a XmlNode and I want to get the value of an attribute named "Name".
How can I do that?

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(path);

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode node = doc.ReadNode(reader);

foreach (XmlNode chldNode in node.ChildNodes)
{
     **//Read the attribute Name**
     if (chldNode.Name == Employee)
     {                    
         if (chldNode.HasChildNodes)
         {
             foreach (XmlNode item in node.ChildNodes)
             { 

             }
         }
      }
}
```

XML Document:

```
<Root>
    <Employee Name ="TestName">
    <Childs/>
</Root>
```

Answer (score 241, accepted):

Try this:

```
string employeeName = chldNode.Attributes["Name"].Value;
```

**Edit:** As pointed out in the comments, this will throw an exception if the attribute doesn't exist. The safe way is:

```
var attribute = node.Attributes["Name"];
if (attribute != null){
    string employeeName = attribute.Value;
    // Process the value here
}
```

Comment: Be careful with this approach.  I think if the attribute is not present, then accessing the Value member will cause a Null Reference Exception.

Comment: if(node.Attributes != null)
   string employeeName = chldNode.Attributes["Name"].Value;

Comment: @Omidoo That approach has the same issue, for example with `<a x="1" />`, which passes the test. Perhaps something like `var attr = node.Attributes["Name"]; if(attr != null) {...}` might work.

Comment: Take a look at [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37322614/1139514), which circumvents the NullException problem and is, maybe?, safer to use.

Comment: An updated answer could be string employeeName = chldNode.Attributes["Name"]?.Value;

Answer (score 45):

To expand Konamiman's solution (including all relevant null checks), this is what I've been doing:

```
if (node.Attributes != null)
{
   var nameAttribute = node.Attributes["Name"];
   if (nameAttribute != null) 
      return nameAttribute.Value;

   throw new InvalidOperationException("Node 'Name' not found.");
}
```

Comment: A shorthand way of not getting an error for nulls is node.Attributes?["Name"]?.Value

Comment: Also true, though the only thing I'll point out is that while you can do that in one line (making it good for an assignment or something), it's a bit less flexible in terms of controlling when you throw an exception or otherwise handle the case where node has no attributes.

Comment: Agreed. Anyone who uses the shorthand way should always make sure it won't cause problems downstream.

Answer (score 17):

you can loop through all attributes like you do with nodes

```
foreach (XmlNode item in node.ChildNodes)
{ 
    // node stuff...

    foreach (XmlAttribute att in item.Attributes)
    {
        // attribute stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: this will be more preferable..:)

Answer (score 7):

If you use `chldNode` as `XmlElement` instead of `XmlNode`, you can use

```
var attributeValue = chldNode.GetAttribute("Name");
```

The [return value will just be an empty string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acwfyhc7(v=vs.110).aspx), in case the attribute name does not exist.

So your loop could look like this:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
var nodes = document.SelectNodes("//Node/N0de/node");

foreach (XmlElement node in nodes)
{
    var attributeValue = node.GetAttribute("Name");
}
```

This will select all nodes `<node>` surrounded by `<Node><N0de></N0de><Node>` tags and subsequently loop through them and read the attribute "Name".

Answer (score 4):

if all you need is the names, use xpath instead. No need to do the iteration yourself and check for null.

```
string xml = @"
<root>
    <Employee name=""an"" />
    <Employee name=""nobyd"" />
    <Employee/>
</root>
";

var doc = new XmlDocument();

//doc.Load(path);
doc.LoadXml(xml);

var names = doc.SelectNodes("//Employee/@name");
```

Comment: The methods above didn't work for my XML (though I wish they had). This method does! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
item.Attributes["Name"].Value;
```

to get the value.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this;

```
string employeeName = chldNode.Attributes().ElementAt(0).Name
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution:

```
string s = "??"; // or whatever

if (chldNode.Attributes.Cast<XmlAttribute>()
                       .Select(x => x.Value)
                       .Contains(attributeName))   
   s =  xe.Attributes[attributeName].Value;
```

It also avoids the exception when the expected attribute `attributeName` actually doesn't exist.