# How to read a particular node from xml in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have following XML:

```
<Loop Name="MasterData">
  <Loop Name="SlaveData">
    <Segment Name="AAA">
      <Node1>hello</Node1>
      <Node2>john</Node2>
      <Node3>hi</Node3>
      <Node4>marry</Node4>
    </Segment>
    <Segment Name="BBB">
      <Node1>00</Node1>
      <Node2> </Node2>
      <Node3>00</Node3>
      <Node4> </Node4>
    </Segment> 
   </Loop>
</Loop>
```

I have to read value of each Node i.e, Node1, Node2, Node3, Node4 which are under Segment node whose attribute ie `Name = "AAA"`. How can I do this. I am referring following link from stackoverflow but thats not working for me.

[How to read attribute value from XmlNode in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600065/how-to-read-attribute-value-from-xmlnode-in-c)

I need output like this

Lets I have four sting variables `strNode1, strNode2, strNode3, strNode4`. I want to store values in above four variables like following

```
strNode1 = "hello"
strNode2 = "john"
strNode3 = "hi"
strNode4  = "marry"
```

Comment: "Not working" isn't an error description. Please show the code you have tried and tell us what the problem is with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a simple solution for my problem

```
XmlNodeList xnList = doc.SelectNodes("/Loop/Loop/Segment[@Name='AAA']");
          foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
          {
              if (xn.HasChildNodes)
              {
                  foreach (XmlNode item in xn.ChildNodes)
                  {
                      Console.WriteLine(item.InnerText);
                  }
              }  
          }
```

Answer (score 8):

You could use [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) to load your xml as an object and then query the specific nodes you want using [XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx). Your xpath query (which I can't test right now) would probably look like this.

```
XmlNodeList xNodes = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("//Segment[@Name = 'AAA']");
```

Comment: `SelectNodes` returns an `XmlNodeList`, not an `XmlNode`.

Comment: you can go one step further in the XPath since OP only wants the innerText using the node() function and the Cast XLinq function. I.e. dom.SelectNodes("//Segment[@Name = 'AAA']/node()").Cast<XmlNode>().Select(n => n.InnerText).ToList()

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend using an XDocument (NB specific filtering based on parent nodes etc omitted):

```
var document = XDocument.Load(path);
var nodes = document.Descendents().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("Node"));
```

**Update to include filtering of parent element**

```
var nodes = document.Descendents()
                    .Where(e => e.Atrributes().Any(a => a.Name.localName == "Name" && a.Value == "AAA"))
                    .SelectMany(e => e.Descendents().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("Node"));
var values = nodes.Select(n => n.Value).ToList(); // This will be a list containing "hello", "john, "hi", "marry"
```

Comment: I have to read Node1,Node2, Node3, Node4 which are under segment whose Name = "AAA". I think your solution will try to read all Node elements

Comment: Have you consider the filtering?

Comment: Answer now updated to include the filtering and selection of values. NB Very few assumptions are made about the structure of the xml, all elements that are descendents of an element who has a name attribute of "AAA" are eligible, rather than just those that fall under the `Loop -> Loop -> Segment` hierarchy

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have an `XmlDocument` you can use XPath like:

```
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//Segment[@Name='AAA']");
```

to get the `Segment` node and then iterate all its children in a loop.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(your file);

var nodes = 
     doc.Element("Loop").Element("Loop").Elements("Segment")
                .Where(input => (string)input.Attribute("Name") == "AAA")
                .Select(input => input.Elements()).ToList();
```

Then:

```
List<string> result = new List<string>();

foreach (List<XElement> item in nodes)
{
    result.AddRange(item.Select(i => i.Value));
}
```

Comment: Use `(string)input.Attribute("Name") == "AAA"` instead. Your code will throw an exception if there exists at least one `Segment` node without a `"Name"`  attribute.

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad - thanks its working, but how can loop through all the nodes selected to get values of all those in a string?

Comment: @NareshKumar Edit your post and consider writing the string output you expect to reach.

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad - I  have edited my post. Basically I wanted to know how do I iterate elements in nodes variable using foreach loop?

Answer (score 2):

You could use XmlDocument and XPath:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(xml);
foreach(XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("//Segment[@Name='AAA']/node()"))
{
    string name = node.Name;
    string value = node.innerText;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Since OP only wants the innerText, you can make the foreach statement more concise by casting the XmlNodeList into a IEnumerable<XmlNode> and then projecting out the InnerText, i.e. dom.SelectNodes("//Segment[@Name = 'AAA']/node()").Cast<XmlNode>().Select(n => n.InnerText).ToList()

Answer (score 0):

If you ever used linq-to-entities or linq-to-sql, there is a [linq-to-xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Do you can try this ?

```
XDocument xmlFile = XDocument.Load("myFile.xml");
foreach (var nodeSegment in xmlFile.Descendants("Loop"))
{
   foreach (var nodes in nodeSegment.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("Node")))
   {

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out..

```
List<string> nodeDetails = new List<string>();

       var nodes = from n in XDocument.Load(@"D:\pfXml.xml")
                                              .Element("Loop")
                                              .Element("loop")
                                              .Elements("Segment")
                                      where (string)n.Attribute("Name") == "AAAA"
                                      select new
                                      {
                                          n1 = n.Element("Node1").Value,
                                          n2 = n.Element("Node2").Value,
                                          n3 = n.Element("Node3").Value,
                                          n4 = n.Element("Node4").Value
                                      };
        foreach (var node in nodes)
        {
            nodeDetails.Add(node.n1);
            nodeDetails.Add(node.n2);
            nodeDetails.Add(node.n3);
            nodeDetails.Add(node.n4);
        }
```