# How to get the String of a XML node in C#

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, xmlreader

enter code herein the XML document :

```
<foo>
  <bar><para> test </para> </bar>
  <bar>text</bar>
  <bar>stackoverflow</bar>
</foo>
```

I am trying to parse it and only get the Strings in bar; by using this way:

*[function where node is the foo]*

```
foreach (XmlNode subNode in node.ChildNodes)
{

 if (subNode.Name == "bar")
 {
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(subNode.InnerText))
     Debug.WriteLine(subNode.Name + " - " subNode.InnerText);
 }
```

}

However it gives me test

Thanks

Comment: I have some code that actually does do this, if you are interested I can post it. I created a web application that will read an input file from NIST and update the corresponding local database with their latest vulnerability information. The source file from them is XML so I have to parse out their data and populate my database fields with their information.

Comment: *without XPath (so XmlDocument or XmlReader*?! Why would you want to discount ways to parse the XML correctly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a particular node from xml in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16147142/how-to-read-a-particular-node-from-xml-in-c)

Comment: @bbcompent1 yes it would be nice !

Comment: @XavierC. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for (EDITTED based on you updated question)

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path to your xml file);
XNamespace ns = "http://docbook.org/ns/docbook";

var result = doc.Root.Descendants(ns + "para")
                     .Where(x => x.FirstNode.NodeType == System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Text)
                     .Select(x => x.Value)
                     .ToList();
```

In your updated xml I see you are using a namespace so the name of your node is not `para` but it's `theNameSpace + "para"`. The namespace is defined in the first line of your xml file. Also you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11933799/1468295) sample too.

Comment: Thanks for your help dude, I don't know why it doesn't work I edited my first post with the true structure but I thought my first should have work sorry.

Comment: Your xml file is not a valid one.

Comment: Your xml file is not valid yet. if you update it I can help you. otherwise you can get the whole idea from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want "test"?  Try following :

```
            string input =
                "<foo>" +
                  "<bar><para> test </para> </bar>" +
                  "<bar>text</bar>" +
                  "<bar>stackoverflow</bar>" +
                "</foo>";


            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);

            List<string> bars = doc.Descendants("bar").Where(x => x.NextNode != null).Select(x => (string)((XElement)x.NextNode)).ToList();
```

Comment: I don't want test because it's not in bar but in para, I edited my first post. Sorry if it was confuse