# How do I read values from an XML document to build a ComboBox?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I'm trying to read an [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) file which I want to make for my mom. So basically this is what I want to do:

1. A `ComboBox` which will show all the vegetable names in the XML.
2. After selecting a vegetable, the second `ComboBox` will show the recipe names in the XML that could use the vegetable selected in the first `ComboBox` for cooking.
3. Last, with a OK `Button`, the selected recipe will read the file path which leads to the recipe.

## XML I wrote

```
<Vegetables>
    <vegetable name="Carrot">
        <recipe name="ABCrecipe">
            <FilePath>C:\\</FilePath>
        </recipe>
        <recipe name="DEFrecipe">
            <FilePath>D:\\</FilePath>
        </recipe>   
    </vegetable>
    <vegetable name="Potato">
        <recipe name="CBArecipe">
            <FilePath>E:\\</FilePath>
        </recipe>
            <recipe name"FEDrecipe">
            <FilePath>F:\\</FilePath>
        </recipe>
    </vegetable>
</Vegetables>
```

## C# code

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xDoc.Load("Recipe_List.xml");
    XmlNodeList vegetables = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Vegetable");
    for (int i = 0; i < vegetables.Count; i++)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(vegetables[i].Attributes["name"].InnerText);
    }
}
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //I'm lost at this place.
}
```

The first `ComboBox` is now able to display the vegetable names, but how do I make the 2nd `ComboBox` to read the recipes?

Comment: You should put the "potato" and "carrot" values into their own node. You just need to refine your selecting process, you're grabbing a high level node and printing out everything within, rather than using a more specific selector to find specific items.

Comment: As an alternative to adding a new node you could put the vegetable name in as an attribute of the vegetable node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xml should be restructured, as you are mixing data when putting recipe names and file path node as the value of the recipe node

Here is a better approach:

```
<Vegetables>
    <vegetable name="Carrot">
        <recipe name="ABCrecipe">
            <FilePath>C:\\</FilePath>
        </recipe>
        <recipe name="DEFrecipe">
            <FilePath>D:\\</FilePath>
        </recipe>   
    </vegetable>
    <vegetable name="Potato">
        <recipe name="CBArecipe">
            <FilePath>E:\\</FilePath>
        </recipe>
        <recipe name="FEDrecipe">
            <FilePath>F:\\</FilePath>
        </recipe>
    </vegetable>
</Vegetables>
```

So to display the recipes you need to extract the attribute of the recipe node.
How to do this is explained here: [How to read attribute value from XmlNode in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600065/how-to-read-attribute-value-from-xmlnode-in-c)

Edit: Corrected xml structure due to comments. Thanks

Comment: The same restructuring is required to pull the vegetable names out into attributes/nodes. An xml element can contain either text *or* one or more subelements; it cannot contain both.

Comment: @Phylogenesis You can have elements which contain both text and other elements. This is referred to as *mixed content*. A good example of this is XHTML, where `<p>Hello <span class="name"/>Mr X</span></p>` is valid XML.

Comment: @Tragedian You're right - but in this case, mixed content makes for an awful structure.

Comment: Mixed content is fully valid as @Tragedian said but I would indeed extract the vegetable name. Sorry that slipped through. I'll correct it

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to get the name of a vegetable out of the document, the easiest thing to do is to define it as its own separate piece of data. There's nothing *invalid* about what you've done, but it's made it quite a lot harder to get to the data you want.

If you could can, change the structure to something like this, so that it makes your life easier:

```
<vegetables>
    <vegetable>
        <name>Carrot</name>
        <recipe>
             <name>ABCrecipe</name>
             <path>C:\\</path>
        </recipe>
        <recipe>
            <name>DEFrecipe</name>
            <path>D:\\</path>
        </recipe>   
    </vegetable>
</vegetables>
```

Assuming you're using .NET 3.5 or newer, you will have access to the [LINQ-to-XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) APIs. These provide a simplified way to to read values from an XML document and should make solving this problem a little easier.

You create a document using:

```
var document = XDocument.Load("Recipe_List.xml");
```

Then you can write a query to get the vegetable elements like this:

```
var vegetables = document
    .Element(XName.Get("vegetables"))
    .Elements(XName.Get("vegetable"));
```

Once you have these elements, you can get their names, like this:

```
var vegNames = vegetables.Select(ele => ele.Element(XName.Get("name")).Value);
```

You can then plug this information into your combo-box really easily:

```
foreach (string name in vegNames)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume, you're using C# in .Net 4.0 framework

You can format your xml like this:

```
<Vegetables>
    <vegetable>
        <name>Carrot</name>
        <recipe>
            <name>ABCrecipe</name>
            <FilePath>C:\\</FilePath>
        </recipe>
        <recipe>
            <name>DEFrecipe</name>
            <FilePath>D:\\</FilePath>
        </recipe>   
    </vegetable>
    <vegetable>
        <name>Potato</name>
        <recipe>
            <name>CBArecipe</name>
            <FilePath>E:\\</FilePath>
        </recipe>
        <recipe>
            <name>FEDrecipe</name>
            <FilePath>F:\\</FilePath>
        </recipe>
    </vegetable>
</Vegetables>
```

Then just use this query to select those items:

```
var vegiesList = (from veg in xDoc.Descendants("vegetable")
                  select new Vegetable()
                  {
                       Name = veg.Element("name").Value,
                       Recipes = (from re in veg.Elements("recipe")
                                  select new Recipe(re.Element("name").Value, re.Element("FilePath").Value)).ToList()
                  })
                  .ToList();
```

Then for your Class Structure:

```
class Vegetable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
}

class Recipe
{
    public Recipe(string name, string path)
    {
       Name = name;     Path = path;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; } 
}

vegiesList.ForEach(veg => comboBox1.Items.Add(veg.Name));
//You can select its property here depending on what property you want to add on your `ComboBox`
```