# How do I set a string to an attribute value in an xml file?

Tags: c#, xml

I'll do my best to make this as clear as I can.

```
XmlNodeList ZONE = nodRoot.SelectNodes("CATALOG/PLANTS/ZONE");
```

This allows me to search for Plants in Zone 4.  When I find one, I want to be able to get the ID # from the attribute above.   I can't figure out how to get this. I've tried

I have code doing this.

```
string ID = null;
 foreach(XmlNode xmlNodeComplex in ZONE)
      {
        if(xmlNodeComplex.InnerText == "4")
            {
             ID = xmlNodeComplex.ParentNode.InnerText;
             .....
            }
       ....
      }
```

This will set the string ID to "PLANT".  I can't find the right path to get to the ID attribute.

```
<CATALOG>
  <PLANT ID = "821">
     <COMMON>Bloodroot</COMMON>
     <BOTANICAL>Sanguinaria canadensis</BOTANICAL>
     <ZONE>4</ZONE>
     <LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
     <PRICE>$2.44</PRICE>
     <AVAILABILITY>031599</AVAILABILITY>
  </PLANT>
</CATALOG>
```

I want ID to = 821

Comment: Try looking at [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600065/how-to-read-attribute-value-from-xmlnode-in-c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you give try to the code below:

```
ID = xmlNodeComplex.ParentNode.Attribute["ID"].Value;
```

Comment: I get the red squiggly line under Attribute when I tried this.

Comment: xmlNodeComplex.Parent.Attribute("ID ").Value; is valid @Piper?