# Read XML Attribute using C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xmlnode, xml-attribute

```
    <Block ID="Ar0010100" BOX="185 211 825 278" ELEMENT_TYPE="h1" SEQ_NO="0" />
```

This is an example from my XML code. In C# I need to store ONLY ID'S inside of a block element in one variable, and ONLY Box's inside of a block element. I have been trying to do this for two days, and I don't know how to narrow down my question.

```
XmlNodeList idList = doc.SelectNodes("/Block/ID");
```

doesn't work... Any version of doc.selectnode, doc.GetElementBy... doesn't return the right element/children/whatever you call it. I'm not able to find documentation that tells me what I'm trying to reference. i don't know if ID or BOX are children, if they're attributes or what. This is my first time using XML, and I can't seem to narrow down my problem.

Comment: Hope this helps you solve your problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600065/how-to-read-attribute-value-from-xmlnode-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use following code

```
 XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Your Element");
for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
{
    string attrVal = elemList[i].Attributes["ID"].Value;
}
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5PpNPk

the above code is taken from here [Read XML Attribute using XmlDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933687/read-xml-attribute-using-xmldocument)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that ID is actually neither *child* nor *part*.
It's a node's attribute. You can access it this way:

```
doc.SelectSingleNode("/Block").GetAttribute("ID")
// or 
doc.SelectSingleNode("/Block").Attributes["ID"].Value
```

Of course, you can iterate through them:

```
foreach (XmlElement element in doc.SelectNodes("/Block"))
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(element.GetAttribute("ID"));
}
```

You also can ensure that it contains ID attribute, so, you won't get NullReferenceException or other exception. Use the following XPath:

```
foreach (XmlElement element in doc.SelectNodes("/Block[@ID]"))
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(element.GetAttribute("ID"));
}
```

Comment: I have tried each of these. The variable is empty. I'm not sure what's going wrong.

Comment: @nanthil Could you show me the whole XML string / file that you are trying to parse?

Answer (score 1):

Your attempted xpath tried to find `<Block>` element having child element `<ID>`. In xpath, you use `@` at the beginning of attribute name to reference an attribute, for example `/Block/@ID`.

Given a correct xpath expression as parameter, `SelectNodes()` and `SelectSingleNode()` are capable of returning attributes. Here is an example :

```
var xml = @"<Block ID=""Ar0010100"" BOX=""185 211 825 278"" ELEMENT_TYPE=""h1"" SEQ_NO=""0"" />";
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
XmlNodeList idList = doc.SelectNodes("/Block/@ID");
foreach(XmlNode id in idList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(id.Value);
}
```

<kbd>**[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WXoS1I)**</kbd>