# Get value from XML file using C#

Tags: c#, xml

I want to fetch only 'Param1' from the below XML file.Please help.With my code it is giving me complete string of values of all attributes under SSIS Parameter Node but t is not giving Param1 in that.

XML File Contents:`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SSIS:Parameters xmlns:SSIS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/SSIS">
  <SSIS:Parameter
    SSIS:Name="param1">
    <SSIS:Properties>
      <SSIS:Property
        SSIS:Name="ID">{6fc5a81b-723b-4821-b948-0cbd44d86c84}</SSIS:Property>
      <SSIS:Property
        SSIS:Name="CreationName"></SSIS:Property>
      <SSIS:Property
        SSIS:Name="Description"></SSIS:Property>
      <SSIS:Property
        SSIS:Name="IncludeInDebugDump">0</SSIS:Property>
      <SSIS:Property
        SSIS:Name="Required">0</SSIS:Property>
      <SSIS:Property
        SSIS:Name="Sensitive">0</SSIS:Property>
      <SSIS:Property
        SSIS:Name="Value"></SSIS:Property>
      <SSIS:Property
        SSIS:Name="DataType">18</SSIS:Property>
    </SSIS:Properties>
  </SSIS:Parameter>
</SSIS:Parameters>
```

`

My Code Snippet:

```
 XmlDataDocument xmldoc = new XmlDataDocument();
        XmlNodeList xmlnode;
        int i = 0;
        string str = null;
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\Sample SSIS\sampleDeploymentDemo\sampleDeploymentDemo\Project.params", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        xmldoc.Load(fs);
        xmlnode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("SSIS:Parameters");
        for (i = 0; i <= xmlnode.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText.Trim();
            str = xmlnode[i].InnerText.Trim() + "  " + xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerText.Trim() + "  " + xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(2).InnerText.Trim();
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"param1" is attribute. You can get it with followed code:

```
        ...
        xmlnode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("SSIS:Parameters");

        for (i = 0; i <= xmlnode.Count - 1; i++)
        {
           var val = xmlnode[i].FirstChild.Attributes["SSIS:Name"].Value;
           Console.WriteLine(val);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
        ...
```

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600065/how-to-read-attribute-value-from-xmlnode-in-c)

Comment: Thanks Melvas. It helped me in my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try XML Linq

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            var results = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Parameter").Descendants().Where(y => y.Name.LocalName == "Property").Select(z => new
            {
                value = z.Attributes().Where(a => a.Name.LocalName == "Name").Select(b => b.Value).FirstOrDefault()
            }).ToList();
            foreach (var item in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.value);
            }

        }
    }
}
​
```