# Escape characters handling for XML using c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have a XML file and its content looks like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Module path="/Automated Meter Reader - sample 1/01 Requirements/System Requirements" Baseline="current" Module_ID="00000080">
<ObjectIdentifier value="AMR-SR-1">
<Attribute name="ParentID" value="Level 1"/>
<Attribute name="custom 1" value="custom value <special value> custom value"/>
</ObjectIdentifier>
</Module>
```

In above XML data the line

```
<Attribute name="custom 1" value="custom value <special value> custom value"/>
```

has escape characters i.e. < and >
I want to handle all the escape characters which are inside attribute value. Attribute values are specified inside double quote mark. XML structure is fixed, attribute value differs according to document of which XML is generated.
I have been searching to get attribute values of XML, but it looks like we need to have valid XML if I want to use XML functions of C#

```
e.g. string attributeValue = chldNode.Attributes["Name"].Value;
```

Please guide me on how can I handle escape characters for above use case.
Links I have referred
[How to read attribute value from XmlNode in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600065/how-to-read-attribute-value-from-xmlnode-in-c)
[String escape into XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132494/string-escape-into-xml)
[Getting attribute value of an XML Document using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750678/getting-attribute-value-of-an-xml-document-using-c-sharp)
[Read XML Attribute using XmlDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933687/read-xml-attribute-using-xmldocument)

Comment: What tool did you use to generate the invalid XML file?

Comment: I am using dxl script to generate XML

Comment: Are you in a position to fix the generation of the XML so that it becomes valid? For example escaping `<` as `&lt;` when writing the value?

Comment: You could easily generate xml in VS.